# Is it possible to use Drupal to manage a static site?

Tags: drupal

Is it possible to use Drupal to manage a static site?  I'd like to have a CMS like Drupal, but render a static site that would be moved to the server for serving.  Drupal would not be running on the server.  Is this possible with Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or a similar tool to create a static copy of your website. This works with any CMS, not just Drupal.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know of any existing functionality that spits out an independently working HTML rendering of the drupal site. You might have to crawl it and/or wget all of it.

Another suggestion is letting Drupal run on the server and using http://drupal.org/project/boost to have it serve static cache content with htaccess rules.

Comment: We are doing some stuff in PHP that we will need to move to javascript, but after that wget should produce the static pages we want.  Removing Drupal from the server mix will greatly simplify our scaling and deployment issues.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a CMS generating dynamic pages, don't use one.

If you need to generate a static site from content *easily* editable, use a tool designed for this task. Like [Sculpin](https://sculpin.io/), [Phrozn](http://www.phrozn.info/en/), [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) (used by GitHub), [Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde), [Bonsai](http://tinytree.info/), [Webgen](http://webgen.rubyforge.org/) or [Cyrax](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cyrax). But don't use a tools designed for completely different (and opposed) use cases. You will eventually needs something too specific and too *static*. Forcing you to implement complicated and un-intuitive logic to *work around* basic features of your (dynamic) CMS. You will eventually frustrate yourself or the next developer by forcing you/him/her to take the complex dynamic route to implement something that should be easily doable in a static site, only to have it *statically exported* later.

Comment: Those are very good suggestions and if I was starting from scratch I would be looking at those rather than Drupal  However, our current site has a large part that is generated based on database entries and a custom Drupal module.  Our content will expand a great deal over the next few years and this module is used enter it and generate related pages.  We like it and intend to keep it.  What we don't need is to generate custom pages based on cookies; we can do all the customization we need with Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of my other answer, for static site generation using Drupal as backend, [Zariz](https://github.com/Gizra/zariz) is probably worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new project that aims to do just that. It’s called [Dekyll – Drupal on Jekyll](http://www.gizra.com/content/dekyll-drupal-on-jekyll/).

> Drupal is no doubt one of the best CMS out there; Jekyll is no doubt one of the best static site generators out there. See where I'm going? And it's no longer just a concept, it is a complete installation profile called Dekyll.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the name another possibility is to use the MAG module (http://drupal.org/project/mag) (mobile app generator). It can create a basic static site out of a given menu.

This is usually enough for most basic uses cases.

I have not tried it, but new on the "market" is also the static module:

http://drupal.org/project/static